# Method Animator.SetBool sometimes is not working (or not triggering) in Unity2D

Tags: unity, animation, mecanim

I have trouble with Animator in Unity2d. I have a main character for my game. The character has his own animation clip for fighting. When the player touches the screen, i am starting animation. When the player touches the screen slowly (every second) - everything is working fine, but when the player touches the screen fast, the animation clip is playing about 10 times, and then nothing happens (the clip isn't playing). I've checked - the touch event is triggered normaly, may the problem is with animator. Does anyone have ideas how to fix this issue?

```
public bool UseAxisInput = false;
private Animator Anim;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
        for (var i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i) 
        {        
            if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)     
            {
                Anim.SetBool("IsFighting", true);
            }
        }
}
```

May be this is because of that at the end of my animation i have an animation event which calls the method, that stops animation.
[image: This is animation clip]

This is my method, that is called, after the animation ends

```
public void stopFighting()
{
    Anim.SetBool("IsFighting", false);
}
```

Comment: Why not use a `Trigger` instead of a `Boolean` parameter and scrap the `AnimationEvent` completely?

Comment: Can you please tell me more about this? I know very little about triggers(((

Comment: A Trigger (in regards to animation in Unity) is essentially a Bool that automatically turns itself off after the state change.

Comment: Thank you, McAden! I have edited my code according to triggers and now everything works good.

Comment: Glad that worked for you. I posted it below as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a trigger within the `Animator` instead of a boolean. Remove the `AnimationEvent` from the animation and the `stopFighting` function you created. Then, once you've changed the parameter type in the Animator you can change the code to:

```
Animator.SetTrigger("IsFighting");
```

Then once it triggers it will turn itself off after the animation state evaluates it.